# Python to get/retrieve data from web Application

Tags: ajax, http, python-3.x, request

I am trying to automate a reporting process with Python 
The Idea is to login to the page and then get the URL :
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/#dashboard/1  as you can see in the screen shot :
but if you click view source it is here is the Html code (Na thing on it ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<title>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</title> 
<link id="css-link" rel="stylesheet" href="css/app_108976.css" /> 
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/favicons/apple-touch-   icon-57x57.png" /> 
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" /> 
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" /> 
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" /> 
 <link rel="manifest" href="img/favicons/manifest.json" /> 
 <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797" /> 
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff" /> 
 <!--[if lte IE 9]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <![endif]--> 
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <style type="text/css">
           #browser-not-supported-container {
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
        }

         #login-panel-content {
            display: none;
        }

        #browser-not-supported-link {
            display: block;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

          #browser-not-supported-download-link {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]--> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
<div id="feature-detection"></div> 
<div id="main-page"> 
<noscript> 
<div class="page login-page"> 
 <div id="page-header" class="page-header"> 
  <div class="page-header-logo-container"> 
   <img class="page-header-logo" src="img/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png" /> 
  </div>
  <!--
                 -->
  <div class="user-menu"></div> 
  <div id="page-header-navbar" class="page-header-navbar"></div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="page-content"> 
  <div id="login-container" class="login-container hidden"> 
   <div class="login-container-top"> 
    <div id="login-panel" class="login-panel"> 
     <div id="login-panel-header" class="login-panel-header"></div> 
     <style type="text/css">
                                    #login-panel-content {
                                        display: none;
                                    }
                                </style> 
     <div class="no-script-container"> 
      <div class="no-script-content"> 
       <div class="no-script-header">
        JavaScript Disabled
         </div> JavaScript is required to use this application.  
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="page-footer"></div> 
  </div> 
  </noscript> 
  <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-6177009-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
            ga('require', 'linker');
            ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.XXXXXXXXXXXr.com'] );
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script> 
       <script type="text/javascript">
            /* <![CDATA[ */
            var google_conversion_id = 973777747;
            var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
            var google_remarketing_only = true;
            /* ]]> */
         </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"     src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
        </script> 
        <noscript> 
       <div style="display:inline;"> 
       <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/973777747/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0" /> 
     </div> 
     </noscript> 
     </div> 
     <script id="bootstrapper" src="js/main_108976.js"></script>   
     </body>
     </html>
```

Here is the Python code that I am using :

```
       import requests
       url2 ="https://admin.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.net/#exec-reports"
       payload +{"apiKey":"8770XXXXXX8t8","username":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX.net","password":"XXXXXXXXX","timestamp":"1449666522626"}
     with requests.Session() as Req:
           url ="https://admin.XXXXXXXXX.net/XXXXXXapi/v1/authenticatedSession"
           Req.post(url, data=payload)
           Response = Req.get(url2)
           print (Response.headers)
           print (Response.status_code)
           print(Response.text)
```

and here is the output :
    {'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'ETag': 'W/"4290-1449645452000"', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 09 Dec 2015 07:17:32 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'XXXXXX', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Mon, 14 Dec 2015 09:09:20 GMT', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS': 'SAMEORIGIN'}
200
and the same HTML that is posted above.
the question is  do you have any idea how can i retrive the data that i need  ? i can post more information if needed 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found the error 
i had to use :  Req.post(Url3,data=Payload2,headers=reqHed )
and build the request headers.
now i am getinting 400 error Code